# Convention of naming a "get/create & get" function

Tags: naming, conventions

I am working on a function that returns an object from a container (e.g an Array) by value (e.g by name). If the object doesn't already exist, then a default copy of the object (default constructor) is created and returned.

That way, this function ALWAYS returns an object, regardless if the object existed prior to calling the function.

Now my question: is there any convention to name such a function so people using my library won't need to read the subjacent code to figure what it does? Something like `GetOrCreateThenGet` or `GetForSure`?

Comment: I'd just drop the "ThenGet"

Comment: ...which could as well mean "GetOrCreate(ButDon'tGet)"...

Comment: No, this is a typical naming convention for this scenario, however imperfect. The method returns an object; it would be very odd to create an instance but return `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need anything other than `getXXX()`. Any method that has `and`/`or` means that it is doing to much and is mixing concerns and seriously breaking the `Single Responsibility Principle`.

Should the caller actually care if the object is being created on demand if all they need from the contract is to get the object?

`getOrCreate` implies you will `get` the object `or` it will be `created` but not returned.

Again why would I care about the `create` part?

If I really am supposed to care it would be `getOrCreateAndGet` to be semantically correct, but highly unorthodox and prone to discussions with peers about methods doing to many things and mixing concerns and breaking the `Single Responsiblity Principle`? Just because other people name things whacky and non-sensical isn't a good excuse to do it wrong also.

Comment: Get is not the same with GetOrCreate, since Get could be in the state where desired item does not exist. I propose Getsert by analogy with Upsert.

Comment: There may also be a `get()` method which gets if possible but fails if not, without creating anything. There are APIs with both.

Answer (score 12):

The best suitable name for the function would be "Provide" like if you provide goods you can ship it from a warehouse or make/buy a new one and then deliver.

Answer (score -1):

***GetGuaranteed*** seems to cover all the caller needs to know...